# Separate the animalNumber from the getSearch and make it cancel if it is already running

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

- my api accepts only 20 animalNumber.
- but right now I am getting more than 20 animalNumber from search.
- is it possible to pass the first 20 animal numbers to api separately and another 20 animal numbers to api separately.
- I put a if condition like this `if (values.join('').length < 21) {`
- but not helping me
- I am trying to seperate the animalNumber from the getSerach and make it cancel if already runnin
- and also to keep the calls independent
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my reducers and actions below.

```or-tag-here
   search response.data--> (150) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]

    search response.data animalNumber {number: "1"}
    world.actions.js:113 search response.data animalNumber {number: "2"}
    world.actions.js:113 search response.data animalNumber {number: "3"}
    world.actions.js:113 search response.data animalNumber {number: "4", expired: "Y"}

    search response.data join---> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15


    search response.data second call --> 

    {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
    config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
    data:
    messages: (2) ["animal numbers in request exceeds the max size limit 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15", "animal Numbers selected for Search: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15"]
    cakesInfo: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    __proto__: Object
    headers: {content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
    request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
    __proto__: Object
```

actions

```or-tag-here
export function animalSearch(value) {
    return dispatch => {
        if (value.length) {
            if (typeof this._source !== 'undefined') {
                this._source.cancel('Operation canceled due to new request');
            }
            this._source = axios.CancelToken.source();
            return axios
                .get(`/how/search?mode=Smart&value=${value}`, {
                    cancelToken: this._source.token,
                })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('search response.data-->', response.data);
                    let values = response.data.map(filterSearch => {
                        if (filterSearch.animalNumber) {
                            console.log(
                                'search response.data animalNumber',
                                filterSearch.animalNumber[0]
                            );

                            return filterSearch.animalNumber[0].number + ',';
                        }
                    });

                    console.log(
                        'search response.data join--->',
                        values.join('')
                    );

                    console.log(
                        'search response.data join length--->',
                        values.join('').length
                    );
                    if (values.join('').length < 21) {
                        axios
                            .get(
                            `/how/cakelist/?animalNumber=${values.join(
                                ''
                            )}&isHistory=false`,
                            {
                                cancelToken: this._source.token,
                            }
                            )
                            .then(responseanimalNumber => {
                                console.log(
                                    'search response.data -->',
                                    responseanimalNumber
                                );
                                dispatch({
                                    type: SMART_SEARCH,
                                    payload: {
                                        cakeSearch: response.data,
                                        animalNumber:
                                        responseanimalNumber.data.cakesInfo,
                                    },
                                });
                                //  callBack(response);
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
                                    console.log(
                                        '-- Request canceled',
                                        error.message
                                    );
                                } else {
                                    console.log('-- Error', error.message);
                                }
                            });
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
                        console.log('-- Request canceled', error.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log('-- Error', error.message);
                    }
                });
        } else {
            dispatch({
                type: SMART_SEARCH,
                payload: { cakeSearch: [], animalNumber: [] },
            });
        }
    };
}
```

reducer

```or-tag-here
import {
    world_TAB,
    SMART_SEARCH,
    SET_cake_SEARCH,
    PLAYER_SEARCH,
    PLAYER_RESULTS,
    CLEAR_SMART_SEARCH,
    SELECT_OR_REMOVE_PLAYER,
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    tab: 0,
    cakeSearch: '',
    cakesSearchData: [],
    PLAYERSearch: {},
    PLAYERResults: [],
};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case world_TAB:
            return { ...state, tab: action.payload };
        case SET_cake_SEARCH:
            return { ...state, cakeSearch: action.payload };
        case SMART_SEARCH:
            let cakeId = window.sessionStorage.getItem('includePLAYER');
            let cakesSearchData = action.payload.cakeSearch.map(
                search => {
                    search.includeSelected = false;
                    if (cakeId) {
                        search.disbaledSelected = true;
                    }
                    //search.disbaledSelected = false
                    if (search.cakeId == cakeId) {
                        search.includeSelected = true;
                        search.disbaledSelected = false;
                    }
                    return search;
                }
            );
            console.log(
                'SMART_SEARCH cakesSearchData',
                cakesSearchData
            );
            console.log('action.payload.animalNumber', action.payload.animalNumber);
            return {
                ...state,
                cakesSearchData: cakesSearchData,
                animalNumber: action.payload.animalNumber,
            };
        case CLEAR_SMART_SEARCH:
            return { ...state, cakesSearchData: [] };
        case PLAYER_SEARCH:
            let type = action.payload.type;
            let value = action.payload.value;
            let obj = state.PLAYERSearch;

            if (type !== 'remove') {
                if (value) {
                    obj[type] = value;
                }
            } else {
                delete obj[value];
            }

            return { ...state, PLAYERSearch: obj };
        case PLAYER_RESULTS:
            return { ...state, PLAYERResults: action.payload };
        case SELECT_OR_REMOVE_PLAYER:
            let obj1 = action.payload;
            console.log('Obj1 --------> ', obj1);
            console.log('Obj2 --->', state.cakesSearchData);
            if (obj1.includeSelected == false) {
                console.log('obj1.includeSelected', obj1.includeSelected);
                window.sessionStorage.removeItem('includePLAYER');
                state.cakesSearchData = state.cakesSearchData.map(
                    map => {
                        map.includeSelected = false;
                        map.disbaledSelected = false;

                        return map;
                    }
                );
            } else {
                state.cakesSearchData = state.cakesSearchData.map(
                    map => {
                        map.disbaledSelected = true;
                        if (map.cakeId === obj1.uniqueKey) {
                            map.includeSelected = true;
                            map.disbaledSelected = false;
                        }
                        return map;
                    }
                );
            }

            console.log('PLAYERResults-->', state);
            return {
                ...state,
                //    , PLAYERResults: PLAYERResults
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you adjust your question? This does not seem like a minimal example and it's difficult to go through. If you have more than one question about two different things, it's best to separate them.

Comment: hey formatted the output and code separately...can you let me know which part you didnt understand

Comment: The output you posted doesn't really match the code you provided. Where is the output for `search response.data join length--->` for instance?

Comment: @Patrick hey I just posted the important consoles, or it will be confusing...do you need it, its just length of 10

Comment: I was mainly wondering why your `if(value.length < 21)` doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @Patrick do you need any other consoles?